# specified colums not found in windows form application

Tags: c#, database, windowsformshost

Hay guys I'm new to programing and I'm making a sample app with user authentication. the database is connected and all working fine except for when I try to fetch the user Role from DB at login this error pops up System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Cannot find column 7.'

I have also tried: Role = dt.Rows[0]["Role"].ToString();

here's the code:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {


            Role = dt.Rows[0][7].ToString(); //Error comes on this line


            if (Role == "Admin")
            {
                this.Hide();
                Admin ss = new Admin();
                ss.Show();
            }

            else
            {

                this.Hide();

                Main ss = new Main();
                ss.Show();
            }
        }         

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username or Password.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could this just be that Column "7" has index `6`?  Depends if Column "1" has index `0` and whether or not there are more than 7 columns.

Comment: How many columns Do you have in table ?

Comment: the table has 8 columns in total.role is the last column hence column "7" I guess.